# Error if not clearing cache after deployment

Tags: php, laravel, git

In my Laravel app, I sometimes want to pull the latest version from GitHub without clearing the cache first.

So I just do:

```
git pull origin staging
```

But every time I do this and then open the page in the browser, I get this error:

```
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
file_put_contents(/path/to/laravel/storage/framework/cache/data/30/6c/306cbe845aa9840ab0c14a1cd4b5d83fd6728839): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

However, if I just do `php artisan cache:clear` this issue doesn't happen.

This isn't ideal because I'd sometimes like to keep the cache when I pull changes from Git. We use caching extensively (on every request) and it's a performance issue if we have to clear it on every update.

For example, the last time this happened, my only change was to a View file. No need to mess with the existing cache.

How can I pull changes from Git without clearing the cache and without encountering errors?

Comment: Did you try adding/confirming the necessary file permissions? I.e: `chmod -R 775 storage/*`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: file\_put\_contents() permission denied — correct storage/framework/cache permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54265192/laravel-file-put-contents-permission-denied-correct-storage-framework-cache)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa Why would the permissions change from doing a git pull? I don't understand this. One minute they're OK, then I do a git pull and suddenly they're not?

Answer (score 1):

My storage folder lives outside the laravel folder. That way I can keep the cache and log files when I update my project.

For this I'm using a custom app where the storage path is defined in the `.env`.

```php
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

class CustomApp extends Application
{
    public function __construct($basePath = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($basePath);

        $this->afterLoadingEnvironment(function () {
            $this->useStoragePath(env('STORAGE_PATH', storage_path()));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. But is there no intrinsic way to get around this in laravel without shuffling directories around?

Comment: If you have set up your `.gitignore` correctly and your repository is clear of any accidentally committed cache files it should work. The `laravel/storage/framework/cache/data` folder in your version control should be empty except for a `.gitignore`file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be someone committed a logfile into the repository. Follow these

1. Give Permission to `storage` file.

   > Navigate to project folder in terminal 
   > And run `chmod -R 755 storage/*`
2. check `.gitignore` contains `/storage/logs` path.

> Not only on your side on everyone who works in the same repository.

Comment: I don't think the `storage` folder is under the `app/` directory. It's actually under the project's root directory.

Comment: ah my bad. Just notice that. thanks @steven7mwesigwa

Comment: Don't you think that **step 2.** is *redundant* considering that the *default Laravel setup* already has a [`.gitignore` under `storage/logs`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/c1dc4199b83466a3a6a8c70953250b0e2ec70001/storage/logs/.gitignore#L1)?

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa reason I've mentioned is in case if someone committed the it wont come to client side

Comment: This doesn't change anything. The permissions are already OK.  It is only after a git pull that the problem occurs, until I clear the cache. Storage is in .gitignore also.

Comment: @svetipetar try `chown -R www-data:www-data storage bootstrap/cache`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam You don't understand. I can run what you said and it doesn't change anything because the permissions are already OK - until I do a git pull at which point something goes wrong.